# SQL Mean Absolute Deviation

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am attempting to calculate the "Mean Absolute Deviation" from the following SQL Table:

```
|ID  | Typical | SMA    | MAD
| 1  | 10      |        |
| 2  | 20      |        |
| 3  | 5       |  11.67 | 
| 4  | 12      |  12.33 |
| 5  | 14      |  10.33 | 
| 6  | 6       |  10.67 |
| 7  | 2       |  7.33  | 
| 8  | 17      |  8.33  |
| 9  | 5       |  8.00  |
```

Calculating the MAD requires:
SUM ( ABS( Current Row SMA - Typical)) Over the Previous 2 rows and current. This is then divided by 3. So for ID #3 it would be:

MAD = (ABS(11.67 - 5) + ABS(11.67 - 20) + ABS(11.67 - 10)) / 3

I first did this with Dyamic SQL, looping through and creating a LAG for each previous row. This works, but is very inefficient when its scaled up to a higher lookback period. I then attempted the below which I really thought would work, but did not:

```
DECLARE @sma_current numeric(20,10) 

UPDATE PY SET 
    @sma_current = [SMA(20)], 
    [MAD] = W.[MAD] 
FROM (     
    SELECT  [id],    
    ((sum(abs(@sma_current - [Typical])) OVER (ORDER BY [id] ASC ROWS 
BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW))/3) [MAD]    
    FROM PY ) W WHERE PY.[id] = W.[id] AND PY.[id] >= 3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Explain what doesn't work with your suggested solution.  And why are you using `update` on a variable?

Comment: I was hoping that the variable would update on each pass, thereby updating the SMA in the SELECT. This just raised an error and later learned this will not work, so I agree no need for variable. The piece I'm missing is how to subtract the value of  [TYPICAL] from the average of [TYPICAL] OVER  the preceding rows. The variable was attempting to bring the [SMA(20)] VALUE into the Window function, but failed miserably :)

Comment: Are the ids sequential or there may be gaps?

Comment: @JDG . . . That is what my answer does.  Is doesn't work for you?

Comment: @forpas They will always be sequential

Answer (score 2):

Since the ids are sequential and there are no gaps you can do the update with a double self join:

```
update p
set p.mad = round( 
  (abs(p.sma - p.typical) + abs(p.sma - p1.typical) + abs(p.sma - p2.typical)) / 3.0
  , 2)
from py p 
inner join py p1 on p1.id + 1 = p.id
inner join py p2 on p2.id + 2 = p.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=237d7da7b41fb5dc76e7b263b35f98e0).

Or with [`lag()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    lag(typical, 1) over (order by id) typical1,
    lag(typical, 2) over (order by id) typical2
  from py  
)
update cte
set mad = round( 
  (abs(sma - typical) + abs(sma - typical1) +  abs(sma - typical2)) / 3.0
  , 2)
from cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=758caa8174b596a80166150178a5eb3a).

Results:

```
> ID | Typical |   SMA |  MAD
> -: | ------: | ----: | ---:
>  1 |      10 |       | 
>  2 |      20 |       | 
>  3 |       5 | 11.67 | 5.56
>  4 |      12 | 12.33 | 5.11
>  5 |      14 | 10.33 | 3.56
>  6 |       6 | 10.67 | 3.11
>  7 |       2 |  7.33 | 4.44
>  8 |      17 |  8.33 | 5.78
>  9 |       5 |     8 |    6
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is very similar to what I was doing prior. Unfortunately this is not very scalable when the lookback period contains 200+ values. There would essentially be a join or lag for each of these rows and the performance would drop dramatically.

Comment: *this is very similar to what I was doing prior* you said that your code did not work but this does. This code is about the question and requirement as you posted it. If there is more to that then you will have to adjust the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using SQL Server.  You can use an updatable CTE/subquery so do the calculation there and then set it:

```
WITH toupdate as (
      SELECT  id,    
              (sum(abs(@sma_current - [Typical])) OVER (ORDER BY [id] ASC ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) / 3) as new_mad   
      FROM PY 
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET mad = new_mad;
```

Comment: I think my incorrect use of the variable is confusing everyone. The @sma_current in your example is static. As per my original example, this should be different for each record. The result should look like this for id#3. MAD  = (ABS(11.67 - 5) + ABS(11.67 - 20) + ABS(11.67 - 10)) / 3